# Typescript. В массиве первым выбирается значение 0

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

Пишу код для выбора элемента выпадающего списка по локатору с использованием Playwright.
Для этого задаю массив элементов, которые содержатся в нем:

```js
const arr = ["Да", "Нет", "Наверное"];
```

Далее в цикле выполняю следующие действия:

1. Нажимаю на выпадающий список
2. Нажимаю на элемент
3. Проверяю что значение в выпадающем списке соответствует тому, что было выбрано в п.2

```js
for (const element1 in arr) {
  //Здесь клик на локатор xpath по типу //div[text()='${element1}']
}
```

Проблема в том что при запуске теста Playwright почему то ищет локатор `//div[text()='0']`

Comment: Вы перебираете массив, как объект. Он содержит ключи 0 => "Да", 1 => "Нет", => "Наверное", поэтому выводит ключи вместо значений. Замените ключевое слово "in" на "of"

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что массивы в javascript (и в частности в typescript) являются объектами. Т. е.

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

эквивалентно

```
arr = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"
}
```

`key in object` проходит по всем **ключам** объекта. Если же вам надо пройтись по значениям, то можно использовать `of`:

```
for (let i in arr) {} // i принимает [0, 1, 2]
for (let v of arr) {} // i принимает ["a", "b", "c"]
```